# overwrite css in iframe/ cross domain with access to other domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am working on a Project with an IFrame. Here is my question:

I want to take the css and Stylesheet from my Website into an iframe. The Content of the iframe is from another Domain, **but** I have full access to this Domain. The parentpage of the iframe has only simple html Content without any Stylesheet or css.

How can I make this work? Is it possible to write a script in both pages to adjust the css of the iframe?

Other questions and Solutions are about the same Domain or cross Domain without access to the parentpage of the iframe-content.

Thanks for the answers.

Marcel Mutz

Comment: What code do you have? Do you have any errors in the console? Are you sure you have full access to the domain?

Comment: could you post of the code you tried

Comment: actually, I am pretty new in the web-programming
I saw some ideas about sending Messages across these Domains but i dont really know how they work.
I am sure that i will have full Access. I will get the Access later.
My main Question is if this is theoretically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if YOU have access to the other domain, that does not mean you can overcome the same-origin policy setup in the browser. You won't be able to change the styling in the iframe if the contents of that iframe originates in another domain.

More info from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)